# How do I add radio button in View

Tags: android, view, radio-button

I write a game in android 
How do I add radio button to select level in View (android.view.View)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts

And then this: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views

And then references this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html and this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html .

RadioButtons go in RadioGroups which go in layouts. You need to know all of this ^